# Statistical distribution where location of peak changes depending on variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I need a distribution that satisfies the following requirements:

- Area under the graph from -3 to 3 is close to 100% (like the normal distribution)
- Area under the graph can be made to focused on to the right side of the graph or left side of the graph depending on variables.

I am developing a software where certain 'effects' are strong in the beginning but weaker later on or strong in the middle or ending but weaker in other parts. I use the area under the graph to determine how strong effects are at any point in time.

e.g. For a normal distribution where I divide 'time' into 3 equal segments, I integrate from -3 to -1 for the beginning and from 1 to 3 for the end. This yields small values. Integrating from -1 to 1 gives me the bulk of effect in the middle.

My program is more complicated and 'time' is divided into around 60 segments.

I was using a skewed normal distribution when I realized that no matter what values I use for skewness the peak will always be somewhere around the middle with the bulk of area also being in the middle. I can't make most of the area on the right or left.

I hope I've made it clear. Can anyone please suggest a distribution I can use? Preferable one that's easy to implement in a program. I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scaled beta distribution would work for your purposes.  Let $X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(a,b)$ and let $Y = 6X-3$; then the support of $Y$ is on $[-3,3]$, and controlling the mode and skewness is achieved through the choice of $a, b$.